# How to mask and format Credit Card Number before saving in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have the Custom field `Credit Card` on my Account object. When User Submit Credit Card information I want to format & mask it like below

For ex: If Credit Card Value is 1234 8907 2345 8101, before saving I wan to format and masks both. So it should like below

XXXX-XXXX-XXX-8101

How I can do this? What approach do I need to take. Will it be possible using the salesforce OOB features?

I have created Credit Card field as a Number (16,0). Do I need to create it as text ?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&type=0 ?

Comment: FYI, credit card numbers aren't necessarily 16 digits long. AMEX cards are 15, for example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number#Issuer_identification_number_.28IIN.29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define Credit Card Number as text (encrypted) field as follows:

[image]

For validating format of credit card, use validation rule with `REGEX` as follows:

```
NOT( REGEX( Credit_Card_Number__c , "(((\\d{4}-){3}\\d{4})|\\d{16})?"))
```

> Validates that a custom text field called Credit_Card_Number is formatted in 9999-9999-9999-9999 or 9999999999999999 number format when it is not blank. The pattern specifies:
>
> - Four digits (0-9) followed by a dash: \d{4}-
> - The aforementioned pattern is repeated three times by wrapping it in () {3}
> - Four digits (0-9)
> - The OR character (|) allows an alternative pattern of 16 digits of zero through nine with no dashes: \d{16}

Refer : [Miscellaneous Sample Validation Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulValidationRules.meta/usefulValidationRules/fields_useful_validation_formulas_other.htm)

Comment: How we can apply validation here? If I enter 8 digits only, still it accepts and saves the values, but format like (XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-7890) which is wrong. It should show error only. What you say ?

Comment: check my answer, including validation rule

Answer (score 2):

This should be done using an encrypted text field.  Credit card is a native option.

Answer (score 0):

In order to transform a field before saving, you have to use a Visualforce page or otherwise pass the data through an Apex class before the `insert` call to the database.  Your field will need to be a text field, and the code looks something like:

```
public void assignToMasked(Account accn, string creditCard)
{
    accn.Credit_Card_Number__c = 'XXXX-XXXX-XXX-' + creditCard.right(4);
}
```